# How to redirect the std errors from console to log file in shell script?

Tags: unix, hive, sqoop

I'm trying to sqoop the data from RDBMS to Hive using sqoop-import command.

if the sqoop-import command fails when the corresponding table is missing in RDBMS. Then in the console, it throws standard error message

> Table not found in Teradata.

I need to catch that type of errors and redirect that error message to a log file. How to do that?

Comment: Is there any return code from sqoop-import you could use to distinguish SQL errors such as missing tables ?

Comment: Yes, I'm returning the error codes . If the sqoop import fails, it returns 1. If the sqoop import command runs successfully, it returns 0. If the command fails, how to catch the std err of SQLException in the if else block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below two commands should do your work.

```
sqoop import --connect....full command  2> error.log
grep "Table not found in Teradata" error.log
```

Explanation:-

> 2> redirect error to log file named error.log
>
> match pattern in error.log

Comment: I'm able to log the output and error messages into the log file. But I need only the specified error message in the log file. How to catch only the SQL exception in the log file and the table name is dynamic.

Comment: you always have the option to search for a pattern like `ORA-`[oracle exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/exceptions.htm#TTPLS195) if you are using oracle to sqoop. respectively true for other databases.

Comment: Actually, I'm sqooping teradata tables into Hive. How to match only the SQLException and log into the error.log file ?

Comment: I'm getting [SQL state 42S02] error. How to redirect only this particular error into error.log file?

Comment: why not to grep only this and related error codes. As such there is no functionality available to redirect only sql errors in logs. [this can be useful](http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/teradata-l/teradata-error-code-list-2461744) to get all the Teradata error messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. grep command worked for me.